# DOMPDF: two inline blocks with height bigger then page height. Second block starts from new page issue

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I'm trying to make pdf with 2 inline blocks. Both blocks has content bigger then one document page height. I applied `vertical-align:top` style to them but second block starts from second page. Any solution?

P.S. Tried to make table with 2 columns, but there is another issue: if row height is bigger then page height - dompdf inserts blank pages before table. Had no opportunity to make rows height smaller then page height.

Comment: In my case I know that second block is smaller then first. And I tried to output second block before first block with styles `height: 1px; float:right`. But it didn't help: in that case second block displays on first page on right position but first block starts from second page.

Comment: Didn't find solution. In result I used wkhtmltopdf.